# Changing global JS variable from a function?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable called 'max' between  tags, I execute a function every 5 seconds that checks the new value for the 'max' however it doesnt seem to change it?

```
<script>
                var max = <?= max_thread() ?>;
                setInterval(get_new, 5000);
                function get_new() {
                    alert(max);
                    max = 1999999;
                    alert(max);
                }
</script>
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue (see http://jsfiddle.net/FXZzx/). Can you say what browser you are seeing this problem in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are loading max from the server you will need to use ajax to get a response once the page loads that is the only way to connect back to the server.

Comment: Hmmm, thats weird, seems like I had mucked up my code, thanks for the effort!